# How to read from a file, and then continue reading from cin?

Tags: c++, c++14

In my program there is a game loop which reads lines from a file, and then read lines from the standard input. What is the best way to archive this?

I tried to put the file stream buffer into the cin buffer by
    cin.rdbuf(filestream.rdbuf());
but it does not work. The reading end right after the last line from the file stream.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to perform exactly the same operation but sometimes with a file and sometimes with `std::cin`?

Comment: Seems like you're making this too complicated. Read from the file until you shouldn't, then read from cin. Don't try to combine them into a single stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iostream classes were designed to be used polymorphically. So just use a pointer to your file stream, and when it is exhausted, set it to point to cin. Like this:

```
std::ifstream fin("filename");
std::istream* stream_ptr = &fin;

std::string line;
while (something) {
    if (!std::getline(*stream_ptr, line)) {
        if (stream_ptr == &std::cin) {
            // both the file and standard input are exhausted
            break;
        }
        fin.close();

        stream_ptr = &std::cin;
        continue; // need to read line again before using it
    }
    something = process(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function that accepts a reference to the general type `std::istream` because both file input and the standard inputs inherit from `std::istream` so they can both be passed *by reference* to such a function:

```
void do_regular_stuff(std::istream& is)
{
    std::string line;
    std::getline(is, line);
    // yada yada
    // use the stream is here ...
}

// ... in the game loop ...

std::ifstream ifs(input_file);
do_some_regular_stuff(ifs); // do it with a file

// ...

do_some_regular_stuff(std::cin); // now do it with std::cin
```